# Combine two textarea inputs into one textarea input upon "Submit" with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contact-form

I have a site that only allows these inputs to be sent to the server upon submit:

- Name (input)
- Phone (input)
- Email (input)
- Message (textarea)

My server can only receive these above fields.

I want to create additional textareas and combine them together upon Submit event. It would show like this on the website:

- Name (input)
- Phone (input)
- Email (input)
- **Message (textarea)**
- **Message 2 (textarea)**

**This would be how it's received:**

- Name: Name
- Phone: Phone
- Email: Email
- **Message: Message, Message 2**

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Here is my code. It won't combine the textareas though. The code is loaded on click of a button:

```
    var h1Text = document.querySelector("h1").textContent;
$(function () {
    $('button.requestbtn').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#message").val("I am interested in " + h1Text);
            $(".rg-modal-contact h2").text(h1Text);
            $("#message").after('<textarea id="message2" class="comments" rows="5" placeholder="Comments, Questions, Special Requests?"></textarea>')
            var _form = document.querySelector("#form");
            _form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
                var msg = document.querySelector("#message");
                var msg1 = document.querySelector("#message2");
                msg.value = msg.value + ", " + msg1.value;
            });
        }, 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real basic example, just catch the form submit. Then set the first textarea value to include the value of the second.

```js
var _form = document.querySelector("#form");

_form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  var msg = document.querySelector("textarea[name=message]");
  var msg1 = document.querySelector("textarea[name=message1]");
  
  msg.value = msg.value + "," + msg1.value;
  
  e.preventDefault(); //just for this test, remove this in final code
});
```

```html
<form id="form">

<textarea name="message">test</textarea>
<textarea name="message1">test333</textarea>
<button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working. Here is my form for reference: [link](http://www.bothellhomes.com/member/contact)

Comment: I also have to add a textarea input with jquery onload. If that changes anything.

Comment: I just aded my code above. It wouldn't combine the textareas on submit. Thoughts?

Comment: So interestingly, it visibly combines into the textarea but the combined 2nd textarea doesn't actually get processed? I even set a delay on the submit too. Sorry for multiple messages.